# make_dashboard function in python

Tags: python-3.x

This is my code snippet:

## Fill up the parameters in the following function:

## make_dashboard(x=, gdp_change=, unemployment=, title=, file_name=)

make_dashboard(x= (1952,), gdp_change = (6,), unemployment = (3.025,0), title = 'GDP Analysis', file_name = 'index.html')

### This is the error message:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
      2 # make_dashboard(x=, gdp_change=, unemployment=, title=, file_name=)
      3 
----> 4 make_dashboard(x= (1952,), gdp_change = (6,), unemployment = (3.025,0), title = 'GDP Analysis', file_name = 'index.html')

in make_dashboard(x, gdp_change, unemployment, title, file_name)
      2     output_file(file_name)
      3     p = figure(title=title, x_axis_label='year', y_axis_label='%')
----> 4     p.line(x.squeeze(), gdp_change.squeeze(), color="firebrick", line_width=4, legend="% gdp_change")
      5     p.line(x.squeeze(), unemployment.squeeze(), line_width=4, legend="% unemployed")
      6     show(p)

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'squeeze'

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that I wrote:

```py
make_dashboard(x=x,gdp_change=gdp_change,unemployment=unemployment,title=title,file_name=file_name)
```

I think that your problem is that you are trying to put a specific value in place, but python wants a variable or string. If you do it right, you should get some sort of weird line graph.

Hope this helps,
Shane

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It would be better if you check out [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page for the future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you